# How to customize commerce order layout

Tags: commerce

I'd like to modify the current order layout visible at user/[uid]/orders/[order_id]

Specifically, I'd like to list the billing and shipping info *before* the line item detail:

1. billing and shipping
2. List item detail
3. subtotals

I know that the the line item detail is a View that can be edited, but I'm not sure how to control placement/sequence of items not in this view.

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice.

Answer (score 6):

For reference there are a couple answers depending on the situation. The order of the field display can be controlled by going to store->configuration->order settings->Manage Display which I believe would solve the OP question.

If you are looking to setup a custom .tpl.php file I wasn't able to successfully use the template suggestions which are:

- commerce_order
- commerce_order__commerce_order
- commerce_order__commerce_order__customer
- commerce_order__OID (where OID is the order ID)

I found these in template_preprocess_entity in $variables['theme_hook_suggestions']

However, since an order is an entity I was able to use http://drupal.org/node/1238606 (tutorial on theming custom entities) and use a template of my own choosing.

*template.php*

```
/**
* Process variables for MYTEMPLATE--order.tpl.php.
*/
function MYTHEME_preprocess_MYTEMPLATE(&$variables) {
  // This is the generic entity preprocessor
  template_preprocess_entity($variables);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_alter to alter the entity theme used by
 * commerce_order.
 */
function MYTHEME_entity_view_alter(&$build, $type) {
  if('commerce_order' == $type){
    $build['#theme'] = 'MYTEMPLATE';
  }
}
```

From there you can use: [sites/all/modules/entity/entity.tpl.php](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!entity!entity.tpl.php/DC) as a template for your template.

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new .tpl that follows the orders path you will be able to expose whatever you want in whatever order you wish. Unless I'm misreading what you're asking.

Comment: I wasn't able to get a template working (tried commerce-order.tpl.php, based on a quick look with devel themer). This might not have been the right name to use....

Comment: I haven't seen commerce-order yet and only commerce-order-email.tpl.php so I would say that isn't the correct theming standard for that. Most of the time it's something like users-order, or page-order something like that.

Comment: Sorry, hit return and posted a partial reply...

In the end, I went with another module, commerce_invoice_receipt, which is a better solution for what I was trying to do (theme a printable version of an order). This module adds a new display to the order entity, which makes it possible for admins and users to print an HTML order that can be customized with a provided template. Also makes it possible to email the HTML order to a user manually or with a rule.

Comment: Ah. It sounded like you were aiming at theming the user's invoice view under their profile.